# RVM won't install system-wide on RHEL 6

Tags: installation, rvm, sudo, rhel

I've been attempting to install `rvm` system-wide on a Red Hat Enterprise 6 system. In three tries, it always installed to my home directory.

I am a sudoer; `sudo yum install emacs` installed a `/usr/bin/emacs`.

Here is the command I gave:

```
sudo \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Except for the `--rails` option, it's a straight copy from the installation instructions.

Regardless, the first line of the output is "Installing RVM to /home/fritza/.rvm/", and the next to last is "To start using RVM you need to run `source /home/fritza/.rvm/scripts/rvm`". There is no `/usr/local/rvm`, which is supposed to be a result of a system-wide installation.

I can't find any reference to this problem. Any ideas?

#### A possibility:

This is a system managed by a bureaucracy at the large higher-ed institution I work for. Maybe there is some kind of access control that blocks me from `/usr/local`. But if that were the case, surely the installer would have told me and quit, rather than switch over to a local install?

#### Other possibility:

RVM chooses the install location solely on the basis of whether it’s invoked through `sudo`. Could there be something in my installation that makes the installer believe it was launched into my environment?

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing error on my part...

I placed the `sudo` command at the start of the line instead of after the bar, for the invocation of `bash`.